# STM32F103 USB-CDC does not work

Tags: microcontroller, usb, stm32, arm

I am trying to communicate my Maple Mini clone board with PC without using a USART hardware. I've configured MCU with STM32Cube IDE which has STM32CubeMX in it. I've enabled USB hardware, set it to FS, set FS mode to CDC. After I flashed that firmware, when I plug board using a USB cable, there is no device shown on Device Manager.

CDC_Transmit_FS functions returns 1 which I think corresponds to HAL_ERROR. I've set the CDC_SET_LINE_CODING in usbd_cdc_if.c as recommended in some other thread. I've tried another USB cable in case other one does not have working data bus. No matter what I've done, I could not get it working.

I am using Windows 10 64 bit version. As I know, I should let Windows to take care of driver installation.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2019 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h" // If I don't include this, I get an error of implicit declaration of function CDC_Transmit_FS
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */


  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      unsigned char msg[] = "Hello world!\n";
      uint8_t returnValue = CDC_Transmit_FS(msg, sizeof(msg));
      HAL_Delay(1000);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USB;
  PeriphClkInit.UsbClockSelection = RCC_USBCLKSOURCE_PLL_DIV1_5;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: Did you impelement all `/* USER CODE BEGIN x */` blocks inside `usbd_cdc_if.h`? Also please include the source for `usbd_cdc_if.h` and remove all ST comment which don't contribute to your question

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully, you are past your issue now. Nevertheless, let me add an answer in case someone else stumbles upon the question in the future.

USB specification requires that full-speed devices indicate their presence to the host by pulling D+ line to 3.0..3.6V via a 1.5 kOhms resistor. Based on the docs available at https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/11280, namely https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/ARM/maplemini.pdf, the board hosts a special pull-up circuit, controllable via PB9 pin of the MCU (DISC line). This enables the device to complete any internal initialization before announcing itself to the host.

I didn't find the code that 'connects' the pull-up in the code that you posted. Therefore, I think this is what caused the issue.

To solve it, you should init PB9 as an output pin and then 'reset' the pin in order to indicate the connection state to the host.

The sample code for initializing the pin is below. You should call it from the 'main' function. You could also use STM32CubeMX to generate a similar code:

```
static void GPIO_Init_USB_Connect(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : GPIO_PIN_9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
```

then just before the infinite loop, add this call:

```
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```

**Additional remark**

Pay attention to the value returned from CDC_Transmit_FS -- as it works in an asynchronous manner. The routine just queues the buffer for transmission -- and the USB stack will only transmit the buffer after the host sends the 'IN' token to indicate that the device may start transmission. So be careful not to overwrite the buffer until the transfer is completed.

I use the below routine to check if CDC is ready to queue more data for transmission to the host:

```
uint8_t CDC_IsFreeToTransmit()
{
  USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;

  if (hUsbDeviceFS.dev_state != USBD_STATE_CONFIGURED){
    // device was not configured yet
    return 0;
  }
  if (hcdc->TxState != 0) {
    // busy, not ready to transmit
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```